# PHP: echo command not closing

Tags: php

I am following a PHP tutorial book.  I have setup WampServer on my system.  Right now, the client clicks a submit button, which takes them to a .php page which has the following code embedded:

```
 <?
    echo '<p>Order processed at';
    echo date('H:i, jS F');
    echo '</p>';
?>
```

which should print something along the lines of:

```
Order processed at 1:12, 6th May
```

but instead it prints:

```
Order processed at';echo date('H:i, jS F');echo '

';?>
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?  I have a suspicion that it is an issue with the server, perhaps PHP is not enabled, but I don't know what to do about it or how to turn it on if that's the issue.

Thanks.

EDIT: Sorry guys, I forgot to mention that short code is enabled.  And even when I tried using `<?php`, it still did the same thing.

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](https://eval.in/329351)

Comment: It seems like you have double quote after first echo. `echo "<p>...`.

Comment: @suslov Your link has convinced me it is an issue with my server.  I guess I'll start looking for help on how to enable PHP on WampServer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

issue is caused by php short code i do not know why but if you try full code it works

Try this

```
 <?php
    echo '<p>Order processed at';
    echo date('H:i, jS F');
    echo '</p>';
?>
```

Comment: `i do not know why`: No, you do know why. You just mentioned it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need multiple echo for this :

```
<?php
    echo '<p>Order processed at '.date('H:i, jS F').'</p>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Short code not working in some server settings. use below code

```
<?php
    echo 'Order processed at ';
    echo date('H:i, jS F');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using php short tags which is not enabled in your case. So use  instead of  and try.

// Code goes here

```
<?php
echo '<p>Order processed at';
echo date('H:i, jS F');
echo '</p>';
?>
```